# change displayed div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get this to work and thought it would be relatively easy but i'm just unable to target my div's with javascript.

I want a list of  boxes and each one will be clickable and each one has a buddy  which is hidden. when you click a , it hides and shows its buddy  which will have an input box. Type the text in you need and press ok and it changes back to it's original  displaying the text you have entered.

the head contains the following:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 
var state = 'none';

function showhide(layer_ref) {

if (state == 'block') { 
state = 'none'; 
} 
else { 
state = 'block'; 
} 
if (document.all) { //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta) 
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = state"); 
} 
if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below 
document.layers[layer_ref].display = state; 
} 
if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) { 
hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref); 
hza.style.display = state; 
} 

} 
</script>
```

And then my HTML contains:

```
<div id="div0">
 <a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1');" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <div style="width:200px; height:30px; background-color:grey;color:white">
   Input: <div id="showinput"></div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
 <div style="width:200px; height:30px; background-color:grey;color:white">
  <input type="text id="addInput" /">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="showhide('div1');" />
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add the following but it just won't update the original  and the script just makes the buddy div show below the original. How can i hide the original at the same time?

```
var myobj = document.getElementById("addInput");
var mytext = myobj.value;
document.getElementById("showinput").innerHTML = mytext;
```

Comment: You mark your question as "jquery" so why don't you use it?  I mean $('#div1').hide(); works really well.
Search for "jquery hide example"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing quote around `type="text` so the input id is not set. Try:

```
<input type="text" id="addInput" />
```